# How to know which controller method will be called from Web API Authorization filter

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I have a custom `AuthorizationFilter` class to handle authorization to my API.
Now, I need to enhance it by adding some attributes to methods which will be read only in
some situations.

I can get the controller from `actionContext.ControllerContext` but:

How can I know which `Controller` method will be called from the `IsAuthorized` method of my custom `AuthorizeAttribute` class? So I can get it's attributes with reflection.

Edit: Adding more info-

If I get a call like `localhost/api/myapi/?id=4` 
I want to get the real name of the method that will be executed in the controller like `GetById(int id).`

That way I could check if the method has any custom attributes I need added to it.

Comment: Mg I deleted my answer as I misread your question. Have you see @Henrik Cooke answer? that works for me

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In web api 2 you can access the action name with:

```
actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName
```

Comment: Please add more detail to explain what is going on.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse what more needs to be explained?

Comment: You cannot add in `actionContext` to web api 2.   For 1 people are already implementing the base class `ApiController` , so you can't implement another base class on the controller ( `AuthorizeAttribute`)     Thus the reason several people have added for more detail

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post any code, but can't you look at the RouteData in the HttpActionContext?

```
 public class MyAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
 {
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var routeData = actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData;

        //If you don't have an action name, I've assumed "index" is the default.
        var actionName = routeData.Values.ContainsKey("id") ? routeData.Values["id"].ToString() : "Index";

        //you can then get the method via reflection...
        var attribs = actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller.GetType()
                    .GetMethod(actionName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .GetCustomAttributes();

        //Do something...

        return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used these to get all the descriptors and arguments within an ActionFilterAttribute

actionContext.ActionArguments["selectorString"]
actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName
actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this from route Data

```
// Gets controller name    
var controller = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");

// Gets action name
var action = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
```